# How to use the verb "to tutor"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am writing my CV, and part of my work experience has been being a teaching assistant. One of my responsibilities was to tutor students before the tests and helping them with their assignments. I tried to put this in a more formal and concise way by writing:

> Tutored students with homework and before exams.

But I don't know if this is grammatically correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition *with* is a questionable choice there. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tutored%20them%20on%2Ctutored%20them%20with&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows *on* as a preferred alternative, though the object of that preposition would normally be a specific subject matter or task rather than *homework.* A slightly less terse alternative to consider, retaining the CV-ese predicate-only syntax, might be as follows:

> Provided tutorial assistance to students with homework and before exams.